# c# remove duplicated rows in data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to display data from two separate tables into a data grid view, I'm aware that it may not be designed for this purpose though I'm sure there is a way to stop it producing multiple duplicate rows as shown below;

[image]

Here is the code for fetching the data (I do intend to include a filter or specific search query later on as commented in the code, this being today's day);

```
private void FillPatients()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

    //DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
    //string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";

    try
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionPath;
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BookingId, Date, PatientId, Firstname, Surname FROM Bookings, Patients", connection);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", timeNow.ToString(format));
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dap.Fill(dt);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dt;
        dgv.DataSource = bs;
        dap.Update(dt);

        DialogResult dlgResult;
        dlgResult = MessageBox.Show(
                "Patients loaded",
                "Patients",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

    }
    catch (SqlException sql)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sql.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: why not change your query to Select `DISTINCT` also where is the 2nd table that you are selecting from..? if this is all stored in a single table then `Distinct` can return what you need like this 
`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct BookingId, Date, PatientId, Firstname, Surname FROM Bookings, Patients", connection);` also you can do a sub select or use a Where Clause.. many options here

Comment: Seems like your SQL isn't quite what you want. Perhaps you're looking for an `INNER JOIN` on `Bookings.PatientId` to `Patients.PatientId` (assuming your schema supports this)?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate" rows?  I don't see any duplicates in your screenshots if all values are being compared.

Comment: @AJ some of these records don't even exist in my tables for example I dont have bookingId 2 with PatientId 2 if that makes sense

Comment: @10gez10 right, but that's because you're saying "Give me all rows from Bookings. For each one, give me all patients." What you *probably* wanted was "give me all Bookings and *the patient associated with it*."

Comment: @10gez10  `some of these records don't even exist in my tables` sounds like you need to make sure that you are looking at the correct table how is it that you can display data but yet you say the data does not exist..? how is this possible based on the query you are showing.. is there a different query and or storeprocedure being called someone where you're not aware of.. have you used the debugger to identify where this is properly being `called / loaded`

Comment: @wgrahm exactly what I was after, the only down side is in bookings I don't have the exact columns as patients whether this is required for inner join I'm not sure though I do have constraint link between them that being booking takes data from patient

Comment: @10gez10 without knowing more about your schema I can only offer somewhat-generic advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(converted from a comment)

What your query is currently producing is a [*cross join*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join). Essentially, this means that you will get each row from `Bookings` combined with each row from `Patients`.

What you probably want is an [*inner join*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join). An inner join allows you to specify a predicate for the records joined from the "right" table (in this case, `Patients`), so for each `Booking` you can get the `Patient` associated with it based on the foreign key.

Note: you can accomplish the same result with a cross join through a `WHERE` clause but it has been deprecated and, depending on the RDBMS, you may see varying performance.

Answer (score -1):

I would gues you need to change your SQL to:

```
SELECT BookingId, Date, PatientId, Firstname, Surname 
FROM Bookings 
INNER JOIN Patients ON Patients.PatientId = Bookings.PatientId;
```

Comment: Wgraham had the notion and R.shilling you gave me the simple answer, regardless thank you all for your help